# Setting height of RelativeLayout according to its content

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a `RelativeLayout` for a `ListView` item which contains an image, and to the right of it (from top to bottom) 5 `TextViews` and a button:

```
 -------  textView
|       | textView
|       | textView
|       | textView
|       | textView
 -------  button
```

The width of the image is fixed, and its height is unknown, so what I want is the height of the image to be equal to the height of the other 5 views combined (as appears in the example above).

I tried doing so in the `list_item` xml, but I can't seem to be able to do that.
The best I got, was setting the height of the view in the adapter's `getView` function, but I'm doing that for each item in the list, and that seems wasteful.

Is there any way to set this in the xml file?
Can I set the height to "0dp" in the xml and only set it once in the code somewhere (instead for each item in `getView`)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a piece of code that worked for me:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.simon.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        // Delay the image, so textViews are created and ready for measure
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageView.setMaxHeight(rLayout.getMeasuredHeight());
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
            }
        }, 100);
    }

}
```

**layout/activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="hello"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello there"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello there"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello there"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello there"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello there"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello there"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Note the `scaleCrop` for scaling the image and `adjustViewBounds` so the maxHeight can be set.

Also note that you need to give some time for the other elements of your `RelativeLayout` to be created so they can be measured.

Comment: Thanks. So, basically you're saying it should be done for each layout after it's fully inflated?

Comment: @Talor right. As the xml doesn't know what size the textViews will be since they are all set to `wrap_content`. Therefore you need to wait for them to be created and then scale the image.

Answer (score 0):

Set height of your RelativeLayout to wrapcontent should do the work, same forYour image height

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but if I do that and the image's height is bigger than the height of the other views, the height of the list item grows accordingly - let's say the views' combined height is 100, the image's width is set to 90, and I get an image which is 90x110 (WxH), then the height of the list item will be 110 (instead of the 100 I want it to be).

Comment: ohh sry i missunderstood your question

Answer (score 0):

Since the items to be inflated are needed in a second activity, I've decided to inflate the layout in the first activity and set its height to a public static member of that activity, to be read by the second activity.

I eventually went with waiting for the layout to finish inflating, saving its height, and setting its visibility to GONE before it is displayed.

```
public static int listItemLayoutHeight;
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dummyListItemLayout);
    relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            relativeLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            listItemLayoutHeight = relativeLayout.getHeight();
            relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

BTW, another option could be to put this layout inside a FrameLayout, and cover it with the main layout.

Thanks for the help :)